# Как в mongoosejs получать подобъекты?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Имеется подобная структура

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f5932d6ebc1e605af745fb"),
    "userID" : "55bb51bdf6f19630b4466199",
    "__v" : 0,
    "folders" :{
            "rootFolder" : {
                    "as" : {
                            "word" : "как"
                    },
                    "any" : {
                            "word" : "любой"
                    },
                    "storm" : {
                            "word" : "шторм"
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

В переменную folderName мне приходит имя. Это "rootFolder".
Далее я ищу коллекцию по "userID". И далее нужно что бы вернулось содержимое только одного подобъекта. В данном случае это folders[folderName]

Как с помощью mongoosejs выбрать эти данные?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, это вам поможет:

```
var fieldName="folders."+folderName;
var criteria={userID: ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР}
db.КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ.distinct(fieldName,criteria,function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

1. Операция `distinct` возвращает список уникальных значений по заданному критерию. Если критерий уникальный - вернет значение одного элемента.

   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct

   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/
2. `"Поле1.поле2"` - это "dot-notation" для MongoDB, доступ к вложенным полям.

   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Comment: Не известно заранее какой придет folderName. Поэтому через "dot-notation" сделать не получится. Я тут понял. Просто архитектура должна быть как у SQL. В том плане, что все однотипные документы должны кучей лежать в одной коллекции и просто иметь id своей родительской папки. Но разве это продуктивней, искать данные в одной коллекции, состоящей из миллионов документов, чем в одном из 10 документов по 1000 элементов? Я думал в Mongo это можно разбить по объектам, подобъектам и т.д. В принципе разбить то можно, а вот для поиска данных нет инструментов.

Comment: @Dmitry, `distinct` вернет [значение], `find` вернет [{_id:*,поле:значение}]. Выбирайте сами, что вам удобнее - готовый массив со значениями или массив с объектом, где одно из полей - нужное значение.
А `folderName` заранее знать не надо, достаточно его знать **на этапе оправки запроса**.